# Confluent Cloud Apache Kafka Consumer - Topic(s) [test-1] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-cloud

I'm a newbie trying to make the communication work between two Spring Boot microservices using Confluent Cloud Apache Kafka.

When using Kafka on Confluent Cloud, I'm getting the following error on my consumer(ServiceB) after ServiceA publishes the message to the topic. However, when I login to my Confluent Cloud, I see that the message has been successfully published to the topic.

```
 org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 
'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Topic(s) [topic-1] is/are not present and 
 missingTopicsFatal is true
```

I do not face this issue when I run Kafka on my local server. ServiceA is able to publish the message to the topic on my local Kafka server and ServiceB is successfully able to consume that message.

**I have mentioned my local Kafka server configuration in application.properties(as commented out code)**

**Service A: PRODUCER**

**application.properties**

```
app.topic=test-1
#Remote
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
request.timeout.ms=20000
bootstrap.servers=pkc-4kgmg.us-west-2.aws.confluent.cloud:9092
retry.backoff.ms=500
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
requiredusername="*******"
password="****"

#Local
#ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
#security.protocol=SASL_SSL
#sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
#request.timeout.ms=20000
#bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
#retry.backoff.ms=500
#sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
```

**Sender.java**

```
public class Sender {

@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

@Value("${app.topic}")
private String topic;

public void send(String data){
    Message<String> message = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(data)
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, topic)
            .build();
    kafkaTemplate.send(message);
  }
}
```

**KafkaProducerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

@Value("${bootstrap.servers}")
private String bootstrapServers;

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    return props;
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(producerConfigs());
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate(producerFactory());
 }

}
```

**Service B: CONSUMER**

**application.properties**

```
app.topic=test-1
#Remote
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
request.timeout.ms=20000
bootstrap.servers=pkc-4kgmg.us-west-2.aws.confluent.cloud:9092
retry.backoff.ms=500
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
requiredusername="*******"
password="****"

#Local
#ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
#security.protocol=SASL_SSL
#sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
#request.timeout.ms=20000
#bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
#retry.backoff.ms=500
#sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
```

**KafkaConsumerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
  @Value("${bootstrap.servers}")
private String bootstrapServers;

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "confluent_cli_consumer_040e5c14-0c18-4ae6-a10f-8c3ff69cbc1a"); // confluent cloud consumer group-id
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    return props;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(
            consumerConfigs(),
            new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
}

@Bean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
 }
}
```

**KafkaConsumer.java**

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaListener.class);

@Value("{app.topic}")
private String kafkaTopic;

  @KafkaListener(topics = "${app.topic}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public void receive(@Payload String data) {
    LOG.info("received data='{}'", data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look in this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your properties need to start with `spring.kafka`. And does your "local" server use SASL as well? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-messaging

Answer (score 0):

The username and password are part of the JAAS config, so put them on one line

```
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="kafkaclient1" password="kafkaclient1-secret";
```

I would also suggest that you verify your property file is correctly loaded into the client

Answer (score 0):

See the [Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kafka).

You can't just put arbitrary kafka properties directly in the application.properties file.

> The properties supported by auto configuration are shown in appendix-application-properties.html. Note that, for the most part, these properties (hyphenated or camelCase) map directly to the Apache Kafka dotted properties. Refer to the Apache Kafka documentation for details.
>
> The first few of these properties apply to all components (producers, consumers, admins, and streams) but can be specified at the component level if you wish to use different values. Apache Kafka designates properties with an importance of HIGH, MEDIUM, or LOW. Spring Boot auto-configuration supports all HIGH importance properties, some selected MEDIUM and LOW properties, and any properties that do not have a default value.
>
> Only a subset of the properties supported by Kafka are available directly through the KafkaProperties class. If you wish to configure the producer or consumer with additional properties that are not directly supported, use the following properties:

```
spring.kafka.properties.prop.one=first
spring.kafka.admin.properties.prop.two=second
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.prop.three=third
spring.kafka.producer.properties.prop.four=fourth
spring.kafka.streams.properties.prop.five=fifth
```

> This sets the common prop.one Kafka property to first (applies to producers, consumers and admins), the prop.two admin property to second, the prop.three consumer property to third, the prop.four producer property to fourth and the prop.five streams property to fifth.
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

@cricket_007's answer is correct. You need to embed the username and password (notably, the cluster API key and API secret) within the *sasl.jaas.config* property value.

You can double-check how Java clients should connect to Confluent Cloud via this official example here: https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/5.3.1-post/clients/cloud/java/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/clients/cloud

Thanks,

-- Ricardo